# Soql : Need help on accessing subquery value in datatable

Tags: salesforce

Am new to Salesforce.
I have used following query :

```
select name,(select Due_Amount__c from Dues__r where year__c=1990 and month__c=3) from contact where Accountid   = '00190000012j4Xi'
```

which is giving the result as

Name        Due__c
    Rose Gonzalez   Due_Amount__c
            1   400.0
    Sean Forbes Due_Amount__c
            1   300.0

I am populating the result in the data table as contact.name :

```
 totalDues = new List<Contact>([select name,(select Due_Amount__c from Dues__r where year__c=1990 and month__c=3) from contact where Accountid   =: selectedSoc]);
        totalDuesWrapperList = new List<contactWrapper>();
        for(Contact c : totalDues)
        totalDuesWrapperList.add(new contactWrapper(c));

/*Wrapper class*/
public Contact con{get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get;set;}
//        public Due__c totalDues{get;set;}
        public Due__c dueObj{get;set;}
        public Decimal totalDues{get;set;}
        public contactWrapper(Contact c)
        {
            con= c;
            selected = false;
            totalDues = 0;
            dueObj = new Due__c();
        }
    }
```

---

Visual force code:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!totalDuesWrapperList}" var="con" id="contactTable2" columnswidth="50px,50px" cellpadding="4" border="1" title="table2">
<apex:column headervalue="Member Name" value="{!con.con.name}" />
<apex:column headervalue="Dues Remaining" value="{!con.Due_Amount__c}" />
</apex:dataTable>
```

---

The problem is am unable to access the Due amount as con.Due_Amount__c as i have done for Name(con.name)

Could any one help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sub query will manifest itself as a collection, so you will need to access individual records in the collection to get the values.

E.g. Get the first Dues Due Amount.

```
<apex:column headervalue="Dues Remaining" value="{!con.Dues__r[0].Due_Amount__c}" />
```

Alternatively, you may find it easier to modify the wrapper class to expose the required value as a property.

```
public Decimal DueAmount { 
    get {
        return con.Dues__r[0].Due_Amount__c;
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Referencing Apex Maps and Lists](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_maps_lists.htm)

Incidentally, the [Salesforce StackExchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) is a great place for Salesforce specific questions.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the help and suggestions!